# UITableview to autowrap long text

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can I get a UITableView to automatically wrap text which is longer than the width of the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dynamically determine the height of the cell, and set your label so that it autosizes itself. There's a fairly comprehensive explanation here: http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

Answer (score 2):

Set the "setNumberOfLines" property of the label to wrap the text to required number of lines. If you don't want the .... at the end of the text if it is too long  then

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

or if you want to show the ... after the text then don't use the above code.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

See the options for the `lineBreakMode` of the UILabel inside the UITableViewCell [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UILineBreakMode).

hth
–f